# How to implement a polymorphic parameter to several interfaces?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, polymorphism, code-reuse

Given some base interfaces A, B, C.... N

And some hypothetical classes which implement a set of them:

```
class MyClass1: public A, public B, public N;
class MyClass2: public A, public B, public D;
```

I would like to create function which accept as parameter an object (or pointer to object) to a class which include, lets say A and B.

```
void myFunc( A&B obj );
```

From a C++ programmer perspective, this seem absurd. From a software architect perspective, this seem like the basic bloc that all languages should have.

Is there any trick (except template) or solution for that?

Note: Most of the interfaces do not come from me, so it is (in principle) no possible to make changes on interfaces.

EDITED: 
Here some example:

```
class A{
public:
  virtual void draw()=0;
};

class B{
public:
  virtual void edit()=0;
};


class AandB: public A, public B
{
  virtual void draw()override{};
  virtual void edit()override{};
};

//This function know about A, B, but not AandB
void some_function((A+B)& a_and_b) { // That do not work
  a_and_b.draw();
  a_and_b.edit();
}

int main()
{
  AandB c;
  some_function(c); // that is not so easy
}
```

Comment: It seems to me the fact that `MyClass` inherits both `A` and `B` is irrelevant to the question. `A` and `B` are unrelated types, so the real question is how to write a function that can accept either one of two unrelated types.

Comment: @Galik: That is the point of an interface: to define some behavior. A is a behavior (drawable?) and B is another behavior (editable?). So the function accept any class which is editable and drawable. So the answer to your question is: not either A or B, but both A AND B.

Comment: Ah ok. So you want to accept any class that implements both `A` and `B`.  Templates is actually the way to solve this, why don't you want a template solution?

Comment: I do not like templates because is one of this very powerful but unsafe features  1) force definition to be in the header, difficult to maintain 2) difficult to manage with polymorphic pointers, 3) It overlap other better features of the language like polymorphism, overloaded functions, etc.. 4) It make difficult or impossible some other features like virtual? 5) Code is difficult to check, as issues are apparent only at usage stage. In a general way: Templates is for general programming, and IMO should not be used as the joker for code-reuse, inheritance limitations, and "everything".

Comment: Ah ok. Its funny because I feel mostly the opposite to you regarding inheritance and temlates. ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really asking for is the compiler to create an intermediate type (`A` & `B`) whose interface contains both *interface* `A` and *interface* `B`. And then to allow any type that implements *both* those interfaces to bind to a reference of this combined type.

I am not even sure how you might refer to such a gestalt type in syntax:

```
void func((A+B)& var); // ???
```

Well you can do a similar thing with current syntax without the compiler creating scaffolding behind the scenes by simply accepting the parameter *twice* like this:

```
struct A { void stuff(){ std::cout << "A\n"; } };
struct B { void stuff(){ std::cout << "B\n"; } };
struct C { void stuff(){ std::cout << "C\n"; } };

struct MyType: A, B, C
{
    void stuff() { std::cout << "MyType\n"; }
};

void func(A& a, B& b) // accept both interfaces in func
{
    a.stuff(); // use interface A
    b.stuff(); // use interface B
}

int main()
{
    MyType m;

    func(m, m); // pass both interfaces to func()
}
```

Comment: Quite clever. duplicating the parameter is slightly confusing, but still a nice idea.

Comment: very clever :) what about template function, that accept single parameter, and pass to func? e.g. something like `template<class T> func2(T &a){ return func(a, a); }`

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class A{};
class B{};

template<class T, enable_if_t<is_same<A, decay_t<T>>::value || is_same<B, decay_t<T>>::value, int> = 0>
void some_function(T&& a_or_b) {}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/Z1MV8w

This example requires c++14, but you can use `enable_if` instead if you need 11 compatibility.  It's just not as readable.

If you want to take anything that inherits from either A or B, use `is_base_of` instead of `is_same`

Comment: I am currently trying to adapt this solution to my case, I will either accept or further comment soon.

Comment: You need to decay `T`, at the very least. `is_base_of` is also a somewhat questionable check.

Comment: updated with decay_t.  Why do you say it is questionable?   I'm still pretty new to the more nuanced TMP details.

Comment: Seem to work, but the template is propagating through all the class hierarchy :-/

Comment: @AdrianMaire what does that mean?  "through all the class hierarchy"?

Comment: Off-topic: I still have problems to use it: https://godbolt.org/g/CjvFX9
To your question: That as soon as any call to this function is done form inside the class, the class become template, and so, any class which inherit or compose it.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I don't understand what you mean about calling a function makes a "class become template".   Classes by definition aren't templates, because templates aren't types.  Classes are types.  I'm probably just not understanding what you're trying to say, but the words you're using have a very specific meaning.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I see what you mean, I guess, but I never suggested making a templated class, only a templated function.  It doesn't require changing anything to inherit form a templated type.

Answer (score 1):

I voted on xaxxon answer,
but f you want to do it in "virtual" way,
you can do class that extends `A` and `B`.

Will look like this:

```
class A;
class B;
class A_B: public A, public B{
};

class MyClass1: public A_B, public XXX{
};

class MyClass2: public A_B, public YYY{
};

void myFunc( A_B obj );
```

I agree this looks suspiciously much like Java.

Comment: Should A_B virtually inherit from A and B in this situation?  In case XXX or YYY inherit from A or B?

Comment: thanks for the try without templates. But practically this is not possible:
- Require MyClass1 and Myclass2 to be changed
- When using more than 2 interfaces, it become crazy.

Comment: It would be problematic in case of `A_B`, `A_XXX`, `B_XXX` and so on.

Comment: probably virtual inherit will help. but will be messy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One way to mitigate cons of template

```
void myFunc_impl(A& aPart, B& bPart); // aPart and bPart are from the same object.

template <typename T>
void myFunc(T& obj) {
    // static_assert to have better error messages
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "T should inherit from A");
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, "T should inherit from B");
    // Forwarding to implementation
    myFunc_impl(obj, obj);
}
```

> 1) force definition to be in the header, difficult to maintain

You just have the forwarding in the header:
code is short.

> 2) difficult to manage with polymorphic pointers,

As long as you take reference or pointer, this part if ok with template.

> 4) It make difficult or impossible some other features like virtual?

Indeed, template method cannot be template, but here, you may forward to a virtual method.

> 5) Code is difficult to check, as issues are apparent only at usage stage.

You have indeed to instantiate it to see all errors.